# Coordinate-wise Matrix Multiplication R

Tags: r

Is there a way in R to quickly multiply two matrices or data frames together such that for two matrices A and B:

A[i,j] * B[i,j] = C[i,j]

I know I can loop through the columns and do it vector by vector, but I was wondering if this was possible through some function?

Comment: Please read more introductory material and study `?Ops`. (This seems pretty basic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is what you're looking for.

Element-wise multiplication is the default in R. To perform matrix multiplication you would use `%*%`.